# Cycle.js HTTP response prints as undefined in DOM

Tags: javascript, cyclejs, xstream-js

I am trying to print the results of an HTTP request to the DOM in Cycle.js.  Right now I am just trying to list the results but they will eventually be in a select dropdown.

I create the stream...

```
const facilityRequest$ = xs.of({
  url: 'http://...',
  category: 'facility'
});
```

Then select it...

```
 const facilityResponse$ = sources.HTTP
  .select('facility')
  .flatten()
  .map(res => res.body.data)
  .startWith([]);
```

But when I try to add the results to the top like:

```
const vdom$ = form$.map(form =>
  div([
    facilityResponse$.map(res => p(res.id)),
  ])
);
```

It displays as `undefined` in the browser window.

However if I add a listener and log the response to the console it displays the array of facilities:

```
facilityResponse$.addListener({
  next: (res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }
})
```

Comment: I added debug `debug()` to `facilityResponse$` and can see the right data, but it just doesn't get added to the DOM for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You found the correct way to handle your *stream of arrays*.

```
// CORRECT :)
const facilityVDom$ = facilityResponse$.map(facilities => // <- this is an array
  ul( // <- notice no brackets here, because you already have an array
    facilities.map(f => li(f.id)) // <- ...and array map returns an array
  )
);
```

However this is not a [*difficulty with lists*](https://github.com/cyclejs/cyclejs/issues/312) problem.

STREAMS are *like* arrays over time, and it's useful to think of them as arrays, but they are *not* ARRAYS and are *not interchangeable* with arrays. Only use streams in STREAM context and only use arrays in ARRAY context—hence the problem with your first attempt:

```
// WRONG :(
const vdom$ = form$.map(form =>
  div([ // <-- the `div` function can take an ARRAY of VDOMs as parameter
    facilityResponse$.map(res => p(res.id)), // <-- this is a STREAM, not a VDOM
  ])
);
```

You have two mistakes here: 1) you used a stream in an array context, and 2) you wrapped what you thought was interchangeable with an array in an array. So the parameter you provided to the `div` function was an array with one element and that element was a stream, not a VDOM object.

---

The ARRAY provided to the `div` (or similar) function must contain VDOM objects (or functions that return VDOM objects). Such as:

```
div( [ p('1'), p('2'), p('3') ] ) // OR

div( [1,2,3].map(ii => p(ii))   ) // OR

let arr = [1,2,3]
div( arr.map(ii => p(ii))       )
```

---

The `map` method on a STREAM takes a function and that function switches you out of stream context. You *can* actually use streams within this function but they're are not typically useful and are *never* interchangeable with arrays.

```
stream$.map(         // <- stream
  function (elem) {  // <- leaving stream

    // regular javascript here
    // transform each element of the stream
    // and return it to the stream
    return elem
  }
)                    // <- back to stream
```

Comment: Ah thank you this makes sense! I'm really liking Cycle.js so far, I wish the documentation was a little more robust! I've found myself looking at the source files and previous Github issues to answer a lot of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that lists are notoriously difficult to handle with cycle.js.  To do it you can either use the [@cycle/collection](https://github.com/cyclejs/collection) library or map over the array elements and combine them into a single item (it depends on what you are wanting to do with it).

I solved my particular case with:

```
const facilityVDom$ = facilityResponse$.map(facilities => ul(facilities.map(f => li(f.id))));
```

Here are some relevant discussions:

- https://github.com/cyclejs/cyclejs/issues/312
- [How to create components from a JSON array in cycle js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150851/how-to-create-components-from-a-json-array-in-cycle-js)